# Swift 2.2: Optional Binding in a function

Tags: swift, binding, option-type

Heys guys,

I am pretty new into programming and therefore I've followed I course on Udemy to teach me Swift 2.2.

For learning purpose I have been trying to program a BMI-calculator where I have a textfield (which just displays the value) and a slider where I can put my weight in kg. After dragging the slider the value is visible in the textfield. I cannot put a value into the textfield so that it is displayed on the slider!

The same textfield-slider relation is used with the height in cm. Now I created an IBAction the bring my kgSlider.value into my kgField.text and it looks like this:

```
@IBAction func kgSet(sender: AnyObject) {

    kgField.text! = String(Int(kgSlider.value))
}
```

Thats works fine but I unwrapped (like the teacher in the course) without knowing, if there really is a value. Okay, I know in this case that there will be a value, but I would like to go more real and therefore I tried to use an Optional-Binding to find out, if there is a value instead of directly unwrap it.

Therefore I used the cm.Field and the cm.Slider in my code but it doesn't work for now and I don't know why. The code is the following:

```
@IBAction func cmSet(sender: AnyObject) {

    if let tempCm = String(Int(cmSlider.value)) as String!  {

        cmField.text = tempCm

    }
}
```

So I created the constant called tempCM which will got the value from the cmSlider, if there is a value. Therefore I casted the cmSlider.value like in the other IBAction into an Int and then into a String. If there is the value it will carry it into the cmField.text. This didn't work, therefore I tried to use the "as String!" statement but know I get always 0 instead of the correct value.

So what am I doing wrong there?

Comment: Why don't you just use this?
@IBAction func kgSet(sender: AnyObject) {
    kgField.text = String(Int(kgSlider.value))
}
Basically, you need to unwrap an optional when there is something to unwrap. The slider's value is not optional (if we are talking about UISlider), so there is nothing to unwrap there and you don't need to use if let syntax in this case.

Comment: Also, making force unwrapping on the left side of the assignment (like this: kgField.text! = ...) doesn't make sense, don't do that. If you are not sure, get compiler help, it will always complain if you forgot to unwrap something.

Comment: @invisible_hand: Thanks for your great help! I have never thought about using unwrapping in the lift side of assignment. The teacher uses the ! for unwrapping the textfield ( let kgValue = Int(kgField.text!) ) on the right side. Therefore I thought it would make sense of unwrapping it there again but as you are right it doesn't make sense doing it on the left side of assigning!

Comment: @invisible_hand: Now I use two functions, one for setting the slider.value: cmField.text = String(Int(cmSlider.value)) and one for setting the slider.value after entering the numbers in the textfield: cmSlider.value = Float (cmField.text!)! and now it does what it should. When I enter the value into the textfield the slider sets itself to the right position and when I set the slider the textfield shows the correct number.

Answer (score 1):

So, this should compile fine and provide you with your desired result.

```
@IBAction func cmSet(sender: AnyObject) {

    if let tempCm = String(Int(cmSlider.value))  {

        cmField.text = tempCm

    }
}
```

You could also try this

```
cmField.text = String(Int(cmSlider.value)) ?? " "
```

in the second example, you are using the optional operator to say if you can convert this to an Int then that Int to a string set the cmField.text property to its value, otherwise use a blank space as the default value.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I tried your first suggestion but it gave me always an error. Therefore I tried your second suggestion and it worked. I also tried to fix my problem by myself and wrote the following code, which seems to work: cmField.text = String(Int(cmSlider.value))